# Simple way to approach bead necklaces problem for equal number of beads

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, polya-counting-theory, necklace-and-bracelets

I was recently given this question on a practice test, and it was intended to be completed in ~2-3 minutes, for someone with intermediate stats/math knowledge:

> For a positive integer $n$, you have $n$ red beads, $n$ blue beads, and $n$ orange beads. You would like to make bracelets from these beads. A bracelet consists of any number of beads on a string in a loop, but your string can only fit up to $m = n + 1$ beads. All beads of the same color are identical. How many distinct bracelets can you make?

I can't figure out how to approach this question. In searching, I found this answer referencing [Polya's Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) but this definitely is far more advanced knowledge than the practice test assumed. Is there any other way to go about this? It doesn't have to be rigorous, simply a practical method to figure out how many necklaces can be made.

Is there an elegant way to do this for an equal amount of beads?

Comment: Where did you get this problem and what does "intermediate stats/math knowledge" mean? I don't know a way to do this without something like Polya's theorem. Are you sure the phrasing of the problem is correct?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It was a practice question for a trading interview, intended for undergraduate students

Comment: @AnnieCarter thanks for catching that, I meant to write $n + 1$.

Comment: still doesn't help about "intermediate stats knowledge" since in a standard definition of that polya theory is not included

Comment: The restriction that you have $n$ beads of each color and can use at most $n+1$ beads on the bracelet is equivalent to requiring that you not create any $(n+1)$-bead bracelets of a single color. There are three of these, so if you can find the total number of bracelets with at most $n+1$ beads, then you just subtract 3 to answer the question posed. [OEIS A027671](https://oeis.org/A027671) gives the number of $n$-bead bracelets (starting with 0 beads) of up to three colors, but it's not obvious how to simply generate a general formula.